How to identify outliers on a box and whisker plot that seems to be compressed?
I have plotted box plots for the features of an ML problem, to identify outliers. I have scaled the data using a MinMaxScaler so that the scaled data is in the range [0,1]. For some columns, the two quartiles are visible clearly, but for some features the first and the third quartile are exactly the same. How can I identify outliers for such features?
**

In a boxplot, any data point below the lower bound (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) or above the upper bound (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR) is considered an outlier. So, what you can do is to calculate these bounds an then select the values that are below the lower bound or abouve the upper bound. In general, be careful, these outliers are not “real outliers” by itself, as 1.5 * IQR is rather arbitrary and is purely for visualization purposes and doesn't consider the use case or nature of the dataset.

In this case Q1 and Q3 are the same value. What would be a good metric to identify outliers specifically in such cases?
